# remove element in array with react, no working

Tags: javascript, reactjs

No working, handleRemoveNote function the App component:

```
  handleRemoveNote(id){

    let{ notes } = this.state;

    notes = notes.filter(function(note) {
        return note.noteId !== id;
    })

    for (var i = 0; i < notes.length; i++) {
      notes[i].noteId = i+1;
    }

    this.setState({ notes })
    console.log(notes)
  }
```

Component Note:

```
  handleRemove(noteId){
    this.props.removeNote(noteId);
  }
```

Call onClick

```
 <span
     onClick = {() => this.handleRemove(this.noteId)}
     >
     <i className="fas fa-trash-alt float-right"></i>
 </span>
```

Rendering of the notes in the App component:

```
      {
        this.state.notes.map(note =>{
        return(
          <Note
            removeNote = {this.handleRemoveNote}
            noteId = {note.noteId}
            noteContent= {note.noteContent}
            />
        )
        })
      }
```

Constructor of Note component:

```
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.noteId = props.noteId;
    this.noteContent = props.noteContent;
  }
```

- App Component: https://pastebin.com/VCrJBdXT
- Note Component: https://pastebin.com/hDmPaGuZ

I do not understand why it does not work, it removes the last item from the list and not the one I want, I made a 'console.log (notes)' and it shows me the arrangement with the elements deleted correctly

Comment: Not a solution but remember to add the key parameter for each Note inside the map. I think the problem relies in `this.noteId`, shouldn't it be `this.props.noteId` (inside onClick)?

Comment: should it be this.handleRemove(this **.props** .noteId)} ?

Comment: `constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.noteId = props.noteId;
    this.noteContent = props.noteContent;
  }`

Comment: constructor of Note component

Comment: Why are you assigning the props to properties of the Component?

Comment: It would be better if you provide complete code of both components.

Comment: @saman.shahmohamadi Well, code links ready

Comment: @Alvaro Well, code links ready

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here's a few problems in the code you provided by the links:
1. the key property must be given when iterating in map

```
this.state.notes.map(note =>
<Note
removeNote = {this.handleRemoveNote}
noteId = {note.noteId}
noteContent= {note.noteContent}
key={note.noteId}
/>)
```

and then it should be removed from Note render() method

2. you don't actually want to re-assign you keys after removal, must probably you will get those ids from the server, so you have to use them as keys. And also it's the main problem here

this way your new notes array won't contain the element with the key which is the index of your last element, so it thinks you want to remove the element with this key - the last element. Just remove that loop and everything should work fine

```
for (var i = 0; i < notes.length; i++) {
    notes[i].noteId = i+1;
}
```

Comment: that reorder of keys is because when you delete a note for example I had note 1, note 2 and note 3 if you deleted note 2 and added a new one had two notes with the same key 3

Comment: then you might need to use something else as a key for your elements, you can't rely on the ids you will provide from ui, the ids used for keys must be unique, possible solutions: 1) you use some internal ids as keys and they will be unique for all the notes, you can use something like https://www.npmjs.com/package/shortid 2) don't enter ids from ui and assign them internally and be sure they are always unique + remove that re-ordering code.